# What is the most generic way to link two independent classes without extra code?

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, architecture

There's a hierarchy of classes describing different properties of some object. The abstract class `Property` is a base class, and it has children: `IntegerProperty`, `BooleanProperty`, and so on. All data is encoded in `QString` and derived classes decode it in their own way.

```
class Property : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // ...
    virtual QString value() const = 0;
    virtual bool setValue(const QString &value) = 0;
    virtual bool validateValue(const QString& value) = 0;
    // ...
};

class IntegerProperty : public Property
{
    // ...
    virtual QString value() const override;
    virtual bool setValue(const QString &value) override;
    virtual bool validateValue(const QString& value) override;
    // ...
};

// ...
```

Every property class must have an independent editor (GUI widget) - `PropertyEditor` (abstract class again), `IntegerPropertyEditor`, `BooleanPropertyEditor`, and so on.

```
class PropertyEditor : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    inline Facer::PropertyPointer attachedProperty() { return m_property; }

protected:
    PropertyEditor(Facer::PropertyPointer attachedProperty, QWidget* parent = nullptr);

    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
    virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;

    // ...
};

class IntegerPropertyEditor : public PropertyEditor
{
   // ...
};

// ...
```

For example, I have a set of different properties. I don't know which exactly properties I have because they are all pointers to `Property` class. My task is to create specified editors of these properties, so I need to get `IntegerPropertyEditor` if the property object is `IntegerProperty`.

```
for (Property* property : propertySet())
    PropertyEditor* editor = createEditor(property);
```

I made a temporary workaround with macro:

```
#define IF_TYPE_GET_EDITOR(propertyType, editorType) \
    if (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<propertyType>(property)) \
        return new editorType(property, this);

// ...

PropertyEditor *PropertySetWidget::create(PropertyPointer property)
{
    IF_TYPE_GET_EDITOR(BooleanProperty, BooleanPropertyEditor)
    else IF_TYPE_GET_EDITOR(ColorProperty, ColorPropertyEditor)
    else IF_TYPE_GET_EDITOR(FloatingPointProperty, FloatingPointPropertyEditor)
    else IF_TYPE_GET_EDITOR(FontProperty, FontPropertyEditor)
    else IF_TYPE_GET_EDITOR(IntegerProperty, IntegerPropertyEditor)
    else IF_TYPE_GET_EDITOR(TextProperty, TextPropertyEditor)
    else throw std::runtime_error("This PropertyType is not implemented yet");
}
```

It doesn't look like a good solution - if I add a new type of property and its editor, I'll have to update this code as well. What is the most convenient and generic way to link an editor class and a property class?

Comment: Do you not want **any** extra code at all, or would you accept more code in exchange for a simpler design?

Comment: Eh, threw in my 2 cents anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want requires Reflection implemented, although there are rather cumbersome and ugly ways to implement what you wanted without macros. I personally recommend the solution of @Chipster.

If you are still interested in methods that do not require Property to provide its own editor... I wrote an example, you can check it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{ //virtual working class
    public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

//two possible implementations
class B : public A {};

class C : public A {};

//Editor interface
class EditorA
{
    public:
     virtual ~EditorA() = default;
     virtual void print() = 0;
};

//Implementations of editors
class EditorB : 
    public EditorA
{
    public:
    void print() override
    {
        std::cout << "Editor B\n";
    }
};

class EditorC : 
    public EditorA
{
    public:
    void print() override
    {
        std::cout << "Editor C\n";
    }
};

//template class used for declaring which Editor you use depending on the class you provide
// I would make a namespace but there are no template namespaces
template<typename T>
class EditorT;

template<>
class EditorT<B>
{
    public:
    using EditorType = EditorB;
};

template<>
class EditorT<C>
{
    public:
    using EditorType = EditorC;
};


using namespace std;

// Recursive GetEditor code... written inside class as a static method for reasons.
template<typename... Args>
class CEditorIdentifier;

template<>
class CEditorIdentifier<>
{
    public:
    static EditorA * GetEditor(shared_ptr<A>& val)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
class CEditorIdentifier<Arg, Args...>
{
    public:
    static EditorA * GetEditor(shared_ptr<A>& val)
    {
        if(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Arg>(val))
        {
            return new typename EditorT<Arg>::EditorType;
        }

        return CEditorIdentifier<Args...>::GetEditor(val);
    }
};


template<typename... Args>
EditorA* FindEditor(shared_ptr<A>& val)
{
    return CEditorIdentifier<Args...>::GetEditor(val);
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<A> b = make_shared<B>();
    shared_ptr<A> c = make_shared<C>();

    EditorA* eB = FindEditor<B,C>(b);
    EditorA* eC = FindEditor<C,B>(c);

    eB->print();
    eC->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Now you can add additional classes `D`,`E`,`F`... you only have to maintain the reference classes `EditorT<D>`, `EditorT<E>`, `EditorT<F>`...

Complicated right? Well... current features in C++ for such programming are limited. It's being worked and will be available in the future (see Reflection TS) but not now. Also it will be simpler to implement in C++20 with all the extensions to `constexpr`.

Comment: Could you please explain which advantages would `constexpr` give in this situation?

Comment: @Nikita I believe you'll be able to write a `template for(...)` (was previously referred as `for...(...)`) instead of recursive code for the `GetEditor` function. It kinda falls under `constexpr` additions in the sense that it acts in similar way to `if constexpr (...)`. I thought it was being added to C++20, but my bad, it's not. Still experimental only.

Answer (score 4):

This might give some extra code, especially depending on how your project is set up, but one solution is to make a virtual function in `Property` that returns a pointer to an editor:

```
class Property : public QObject
{
public:
    virtual PropertyEditor* CreateEditor(PropertySetWidget* widget) {
        // let's put our default behavior here
        throw std::runtime_error("This PropertyType is not implemented yet");
    }
    //...
};
```

Now, you make each class responsible for supplying its own editor:

```
class IntegerProperty : public Property
{
public:
    // doesn't have to be virtual, I don't think Just a regular version should be fine too.
    virtual PropertyEditor* CreateEditor(PropertySetWidget* widget) {
        return new  IntegerPropertyEditor(this, widget);
    }
    //...
};
```

Depending on how many classes you have, that may be a lot of copying and pasting.

However, the fun part is `PropertySetWidget::create()`:

```
PropertyEditor *PropertySetWidget::create(PropertyPointer property)
{
    return property->CreateEditor(this);
}
```

Because every child of `property` is responsible for supplying its own editor, we don't have to worry about it at this level. If one doesn't exist/isn't implemented, `property::CreateEditor()` will throw an error for you. If one does exist/is implemented, it will return a pointer to a new instance the editor automatically.

The big advantage is that if you add a new property and its editor, you don't have to touch it this function at all. The virtual function takes care of properly implementing it for you. If the new property has an editor, it just needs to overload that function, and this `create()` still works properly.

Of course, you will have to modify `Property`'s interface this way, which may not be feasible in your case. That's the major drawback to this approach.

Comment: Yup, that had been the first idea I came up with, but the team lead rejected it and stated that it wouldn't be a good idea to add GUI-specified things in classes that doesn't have something to do with it

Comment: Yeah, he may have a point there too. Well, the other solution is ALX23z's solution, which I like, which makes a templated `EditorT` class which links them.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer above about each Property having a virtual method to return the appropriate type of editor. The only downside to that is that it may tie user interface-related elements into your lower-level code. Depending on your needs, that may or may not be OK.

A variation of your original factory that keeps the editor creation separate from the property class definitions is that you could add a "propertyType" virtual method that returns an integer, and then your factory becomes a switch statement:

```
switch (Property.propertyType ())
{
    case BooleanPropertyType: create Boolean property editor
    case StringPropertyType:  create String properly editor
    etc.
}
```

You would have an enum somewhere with the defined property type values. It's the same basic idea, but it avoids the overhead of the dynamic cast. (Whether or not it's actually faster is something to test.)

I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with your approach other than the possible dynamic_cast overhead, and often, I think that having a factory method where all of the editors are created for all of the types can be easier to maintain than creating the UI elements in classes where you're trying to manage data. Purists may see this as a violation of good object oriented classes, but it really depends on your needs and who you're trying to please.

Comment: The only issue is that this doesn't solve the extend-ability problem. If the OP adds new properties, they still have to change this function.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's where the other suggested approach has an advantage.